# How can I reliably link to a Gmail conversation given a thread ID if the user is logged into multiple accounts?

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-oauth, google-openid, gmail-api

If you're logged into multiple Gmail accounts, Google changes the URLs to reference which account you're currently using. For example:

`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/138d85da096d2126` for a convo in my primary account vs
`https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#inbox/128cfe99d055805d` for a convo in another one of my accounts.

Note that one account has `/u/0` in the URL and the other has `u/1`.

My question is: given that I've used the Gmail REST API to find the ID of a particular thread, how can I reliably link to that thread? Is there any programmatic way to ask Google which accounts the user is logged into, and what sequence (0, 1, 2, ...) each account falls under?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you can include a query parameter called `authUser` that specifies the email account you want to link to:

https://mail.google.com/mail/?authuser=your.email.address@gmail.com#all/138d85da096d2126

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it and it worked. What's happening when you try it?

Comment: if your account isnt logged in, it doesnt prompt you to log into that user. it just tries using the /0/ account

Comment: Correct, this only works for users who are logged in.