# Reliable Gmail draft compose link when user is signed in multiple Google Accounts

Tags: gmail-api

I am creating a draft in GMail via API and then user is redirected to the draft on following URL, for review and then send email.

https://mail.google.com/mail/#drafts?compose=id

That works when the user is signed in to exactly one Google Account and that specific account on which the draft was created.

But if user is signed in on multiple Google Accounts. The link may not work, depending on the index of Google Account on which the draft was created.

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose=15509443ce39e641
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#drafts?compose=15509443ce39e641

Browsing stackoverflow i came across 
[an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26390177/6398800) which suggests the use of `authUser` parameter in URL to hyperlink to specific Google Account.

https://mail.google.com/mail/?authuser=your.email.address@gmail.com#all/138d85da096d2126

But i am not sure how do i utilise this queryString parameter in `#drafts?compose=id` or if it even works here.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following works:

https://mail.google.com/mail/?authuser=your.email.address@gmail.com#drafts/id

Comment: If a user is:
* NOT signed in on Google Account on which the draft was created
* AND signed in on another Google Account

Following message is shown instead of redirect to login screen:
'The conversation that you requested no longer exists.'