# How to have an authenticated GCS URL without ?authuser=1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a fairly simple task... I have a GCS bucket I created that I want to be private.

I programmatically put files into it, and use it in my (personal use only) web app.

I want to create an `<img src="">` tag which links directly to the URL but only if I'm logged into the proper Google account.

I've tried adding "Legacy object reader" as well as "object reader" permissions for the particular Google email in question.

The authentication works when using this URL but ONLY if I add `?authuser=X`:

```
https://storage.cloud.google.com/<BUCKET_NAME>/<PATH>
```

If I don't add that then it shows 403 forbidden error.

Is there a way I can do this without having to specify the # of user signed in (I change them and the order frequently), and without the headache of signed URLs?

Comment: There's a suggestion here that you may be able to specify the account by name for authuser. I haven't tried it, but maybe it would work for your use case?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26390177/81491

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [default service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts) account to grant access to your bucket and files through your web app and if your app is hosted in App Engine, you can use [Identity-Aware proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/) to allow access only to your account.

Answer (score 0):

It happens if you are logged in with multiple Google/Gmail users in the browser, to give you the possibility to select the user.

Check in the top right here if you are logged in with multiple users:
https://console.cloud.google.com/

You have to sign out from all but one to make the URL without ?authuser=1 to work.

Example for me that give problem (require ?authuser=1):

[image]